# Simple Linux Shell - execvp() failing

Tags: c, shell, exec, execvp

I need some help with a simple shell for class, and I'm worried I don't quite understand how the execvp() function works.

The shell does not do much, does not support piping, redirection, scripting or anything fancy like that.  It only reads a command, reads in the options (with the command as option[0]), and forks.

It worked a few times, then started giving me errors about not being able to find commands.  Other similar questions posted here had to do with piping or redirection.

Please forgive the noobcode, it's not pretty, but I hope it's legible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define OPT_AMT 10

const size_t SIZE = 256;
int i = 0;
int o = 0;

int main(void) {

    // initializing data

    int exit = 0;
    char cwd[SIZE];
    char cmd[SIZE];
    char input[SIZE * OPT_AMT];
    char *opt[OPT_AMT];
    getcwd(cwd, SIZE);

    // main loop

    while (exit == 0) {
        // reset everything
        o = 1;
        i = 0;
        cmd[0] = "\0";
        while (i < OPT_AMT) {
            opt[i++] = "\0";
        }

        // get input
        printf("%s $ ", cwd);
        scanf("%s", cmd);
        gets(input);
        opt[0] = cmd;

        char *t = strtok(input, " ");
        while (t != NULL) {
            opt[o++] = t;
            t = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        // if exit, exit
        if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
            exit = 1;
        }
        // else fork and execute
        else {
            pid_t pID = fork();

            if (pID == 0) { // child process
                execvp(cmd, opt);
            } else if (pID < 0) { // failed to fork
                printf("\nFailed to fork\n");
            } else { // parent process
                wait(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // cleanup

    printf("\nFinished!  Exiting...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Anything blatantly wrong?  I most recently added the exit condition and the resetting the options array.

Also, this is my first question, so remind me of any rules I may have broken.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It's inherently unsafe, and it's not even part of C anymore. Use `fgets()` instead, and don't forget to remove the newline character at the end, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, this

```
cmd[0] = "\0";
```

ought to be

```
cmd[0] = '\0';
```

Listen to your compiler's warnings.

To enable them use the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (for gcc).

---

Also you might better want to initalise `opt`'s elements to point to "nothing", that is `NULL` but to the literal `"\0"`:

```
    while (i < OPT_AMT) {
        opt[i++] = NULL;
    }
```

as [`execvp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) requires `opt` to be a `NULL`-terminated array of C-"strings" (thanks [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399879/paul-griffiths) for mentioning/wording the relevant background).

---

Also^2: Do not use `gets()`, as it's evil and not even part of the C Standard anymore. Instead of

```
gets(input);
```

use

```
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
```

`gets()` easyly let's the user overflow the (input) buffer passed. (Mentioning this came to my mind without Paul, btw ... ;-))

Comment: Indeed, `execvp()` requires `opt` to be a `NULL`-terminated list of strings.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made the changes, but its giving me the same error.  Does this have something to do with the newline character from fgets?

Comment: @Will: You'd really help yourself out a lot if you took some steps to figure out what your program is doing, like `printf()`ing the value of `cmd`, and of each element of `opt`, before your `execvp()` call so you can actually see what you're passing to it. Doing that will answer most of these types of question.

Comment: @Will: Using a debugger to trace the code and inspect the (intermediate) values of the varibales involved might also help.

Comment: Ok, so it works fine with gets(), I just need to look a little deeper into fgets().  Thanks for the help @alk and @Paul_Griffiths!